# Jquery Datatable : makeEditable not a function error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

This is the code I have, but it errors on firebug saying `$("#updateTable").dataTable({bServerSide: true, sAjaxSource: "UpdateTS", bProcessing: true, aoColumns: [{sName: "ID"}, {sName: "Result"}]}).makeEditable is not a function`

```
<link href="../../Content/CSS/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {

       $('#updateTable').dataTable({
               "bServerSide": true,
               "sAjaxSource": "UpdateTS",
               "bProcessing": true,
               "aoColumns": [
                   { "sName": "ID" },
                   { "sName": "Result" }
               ]
           }).makeEditable();
   });

</script>
```

This error is causing the datatable not editable. Am I not using editable plug-in right?

The makeEditable function is defined in the plug-in [../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/source/browse/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.editable.js?r=77)

Comment: where is `makeEditable()` supposed to be defined?  Can you post the code for where it is defined?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: The makeEditable() is defined in "../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried changing your script include for that library to:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

It looks like a few other libraries you are using might have this same issue.

Comment: Wow! that worked, can you explain how that made a difference?

Comment: Take a look at this SO Post for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work  Basically the `Script` tag is not self closing.