# Datatable makeEditable() is Not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

```
angular.js:11594 TypeError: undefined is not a function
at ini_table (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/assets/js/controller.js:127:15)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/assets/js/controller.js:26:5)
at j (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:26911)
at Object.k.add [as done] (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:27220)
at n.fn.ready (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js:2:29326)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/assets/js/controller.js:21:16)
at e (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:37:96)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:37:207)
at http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:76:267
at link (http://localhost/ferpa-quiz-client/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js:7:248) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

This is the error I am getting and blow is my code. Everything works after removing .makeEditable().

```
$("#questiontable").DataTable(
            {
                bAutoWidth: true,
                bProcessing: true,
                ajax: '../api/ferpa-quiz/public/getallquestion',
                sDom: '<"$grid-toolbar"sF>tr<"dataTables-footer"ilp>',
                iDisplayLength: 5,

                aoColumns: [
                    { 
                        mData: 'QUESTION',
                        sTitle: "QUESTION"

                    }


                ]

            }
        ).makeEditable();
```

Html

```
<script src="bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="bower_components/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="bower_components/ediTable/jquery.dataTables.editable.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jeditable/js/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
```

Things I have tried:
1. switching 'D' to 'd'. Neither works
2. change the order of script references. Doesn't work.

[JQuery 1.10.2 Datatable makeEditable() is Not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466506/jquery-1-10-2-datatable-makeeditable-is-not-a-function)

Comment: You're only referencing 2 out of the 6 required scripts in this post. If you are referencing the other 4 please include them in your example - in the correct order - that way we can eliminate that issue as a possibility. `jquery.jeditable.js` is required for this to work as well.

Comment: Posting as an answer, as there's not enough comment space

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/HTMLSource  I found it. Thank you.

Comment: I posted the answer anyway, as it was nearly finished. Let me know if your code works, and if not, I'll help you troubleshoot the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Script Order:**

From your example, it could be that the scripts are being loaded out of order. The example given on the [dataTables](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html) website has the scripts loaded in this order:

```
jquery.min.js
jquery.dataTables.min.js
jquery.jeditable.js
jquery-ui.js
jquery.validate.js //not sure this one is strictly needed
jquery.dataTables.editable.js
```

`jeditable` is a required script as `dataTables.editable` calls it. That also means `jeditable` needs to be loaded *before* `dataTables.editable`.

**JQuery in Angular JS:**

I'm not terrible familiar with angular js, but from their documentation...

> Does Angular use the jQuery library?
>
> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped.
>   If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to
>   its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.

And, JQLite is not the same as JQuery... You need JQuery for `dataTable`. Note:

> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer
>   might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

So, the version matters as well.